# PDO database not adding items to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have just got a school assignment to practice PDO. The problem is i seem to get it to connect to database but can't get it to insert or count rows in database. This might be a possible duplicate question did try to search for answers but might just been asking wrong questions.

```
<?php
 include("db.class.php");

 class uppClass extends Database {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function countUsers() {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 500");
        $stmt->execute();
        return count( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );
    }

}
?>
```

next class handles the pdo connection

```
<?php
include("db-details.php");

class Database {

    public $connection;

    /**
     * Opens a connection to the DB
     */

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->DATABASE_ADDRESS;dbname=$this->DATABASE_NAME;", DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 

}
?>
```

Comment: Are these classes a part of assignment? Can you go without them, with just PDO?

Comment: We did get those specific class to do out homework with but if nothing else i guess it could be done some other way just to get something to turn in.

Comment: I'd suggest to go with raw PDO first, as it hard to learn two things at once.

Comment: Alright thanks for you quick response ill do that.

Comment: Can you make an insert with raw PDO? Do you need assistance with it? As of the count, you should never select the rows to count them. Do a `SELECT count(*)` query instead. I wrote a [tutorial on PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), you may find it useful.

Comment: Actually i did run into a problem with it i get a error "Call to a member function execute() on a non-object" as for the count ill keep that in mind and ill be sure to read trough your tutorial for PDO later and hopefully atleast have a bit more understanding with PDO.

Comment: Even though you could do things a bit differently, like using `$this->connection->query()` instead of prepare/execute as you are not binding any variables, that is not the problem. The problem is the way you handle your classes, but you should post the complete code (where do you instantiate class `uppClass` for example? That is the key in this case. Something like: `$obj = new uppClass();
print_r($obj->countUsers());` will work.

Answer (score -1):

To count the rows using PDO you can use this.

```
public function countUsers() {
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 500");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```